# How to remove numbers from every list entry

Tags: list, python-3.x

I have a csv file with the following entries:

```
"Last,First,HW1,HW2,HW3,HW4,Test 1,Test 2"
```

I want to remove the numbers from the HWs and the Tests. So the result would be:

```
"Last,First,HW,HW,HW,HW,Test ,Test"
```

Is there some way to do this?

Comment: If you want to avoid getting voted down in the future, you should at least show some effort in trying to solve the problem yourself. SO is not a code service. That being said: your problem wasn't very difficult to solve, and I felt like being nice today. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
def main(ifilename, ofilename):
    with open(ifilename,'r') as i, open(ofilename,'w') as o:
        for line in i:
            for digit in (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9):
                line = line.replace(str(digit), '')
            print(line,file=o,end='')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from sys import argv
    main(argv[1], argv[2])
```

Use the script from the command line like this:

```
python my_script.py input.csv output.csv
```